# JavaScript callback running out of order in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, web, callback

I am trying to call a function AFTER another function has completed. Normally, this is done with callbacks, at least with Node.js. However, when I try to run the following code in Chrome, the callback function seems to execute before the main function. Am I writing my function/callback wrong? Shouldn't the second function (the callback function) only execute after the first one is complete?

If callbacks don't work when the javascript is running client-side in the browser, is there another way I can ensure the second function runs only when the first function is complete?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

function firstLoad(callback) {
  console.log("firstLoad function fired.");
}

function secondLoad() {
  console.log("secondLoad function fired.");
}

firstLoad(secondLoad());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome Developer Tools Console, the above code gives me:

> secondLoad function fired.
>
> firstLoad function fired.

I would expect it to be the other way around.

Comment: what you are seeing is exactly what I would have expected, call the callback in `firstLoad` by passing it instead of evaluating it `firstLoad(secondLoad);` to change this with `callback()` somewhere in there (at the end?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to give a simpler answer here that gets straight to the point, I have edited your code so it's working the way you are expecting it to work and added some comments to explain what's happening:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <script>

    function firstLoad(callback) { //secondLoad is "saved" in the callback variable
      console.log("firstLoad function fired.");

      //When Firstload is done with doing all it has to do you have to manually call 
      //the callback which references to the secondLoad function:
      callback();
    }

    function secondLoad() {
      console.log("secondLoad function fired.");
    }

    //Here you pass the secondLoad function as a parameter for the firstLoad function,
    //in your code you were passing the *result* of secondLoad
    firstLoad(secondLoad); 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am assuming that firstLoad is not doing asynchronous stuff like network requests

Answer (score 1):

Expressions in an argument list are evaluated immediately, so that the expression can be passed to the function. So with

```
firstLoad(secondLoad());
```

`secondLoad` is called and evaluated to

```
firstLoad(undefined);
```

before `firstLoad` is called.

If `firstLoad` is asynchronous, pass just the `secondLoad` function name instead, and call it as a callback at the end of the asynchronous action:

```js
function firstLoad(callback) {
  console.log("firstLoad function fired.");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('firstload done');
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}

function secondLoad() {
  console.log("secondLoad function fired.");
}

firstLoad(secondLoad);
```

You can also have `firstLoad` return a Promise:

```js
function firstLoad() {
  console.log("firstLoad function fired.");
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('firstload done');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function secondLoad() {
  console.log("secondLoad function fired.");
}

firstLoad()
  .then(secondLoad);
```

Of course, if `firstLoad` isn't asynchronous, just call `secondLoad` after `firstLoad`:

```js
function firstLoad(callback) {
  console.log("firstLoad function fired.");
}

function secondLoad() {
  console.log("secondLoad function fired.");
}

firstLoad();
secondLoad();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't tried your suggestion yet. Is there a way to tell if my function is asynchronous or not? Some functions I have are acting like they're asynchronous, but I didn't explicitly declare them as async.

Comment: Look at the function's code - it should be pretty clear if one is doing something asynchronous or not. There's no magic keyword that will always be present if something asynchronous is being done (though if you see `await` inside an `async` function, it'll be asynchronous). There might also be `setTimeout` or just some callback

Comment: For the record: That was not my downvote on your just-deleted answer. :-)